# Template Engine [ejs] <%= %> in .ejs file marked as wrong but correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-deployment, template-engine

Code marks <%= %> and <% %> expressions in .ejs files as wrong and marks them red with the hint "[js] Expression expected". But this should be allowed in ejs files.

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62254530/11024771