# EJS is working fine but no colors are showing on EJS syntax?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I installed EJS and it's clearly working with me, as I used its syntax to output data and it's working.
However, no colors are showing on the EJS syntax, which makes it difficult to read for the eye.

I appreciate your help if you can guide me on how to colorize the syntax.
Thank you!

Example for no colors appearing on EJS syntax:

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59238175/visual-studio-code-isnt-recognising-ejs

Comment: @evolutionxbox It worked! much appreciated brother.